# VS 2017 won't open VS 2015 ETL solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I inherited a project that was created in Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server Data Tools version 14.

I'm running VS 2017 version 15.6.0 with SQL Server Data Tools 15.1.61801.210

When I try to open the solution it just fails with the below error message.  What do I need to do in order to "upgrade" the solution so I can work with it?

> Unsupported
>   This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
>   For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
>                 - LabSOR, "C:\Users\GROSCH\Documents\LabSOR\ETL\LabSOR_SSIS\LabSOR\LabSOR.dtproj"
>
> No changes required
>   These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
>                 - LabSOR, "C:\Users\GROSCH\Documents\LabSOR\ETL\LabSOR_SSIS\LabSOR.sln"

Answer (score 0):

Ended up the SSDT integration elements hadn't installed.  Once I did that I could right-click on the project in the solution explorer and reload it, and then it started working.